# My function always reads date wrong by exactly 1 year

Tags: excel, vba

I have dates stored in strings, sometimes in the form of "Nov-2018" and sometimes in the form of "11/1/2018". I want to change them universally to "Nov 2018". Just month and date.

I wrote the following function.

```
Function FnDateExtract(fnFile, fnTab, fnRow, fnColumn)
    Dim RawExtract As String
    With Workbooks(fnFile).Worksheets(fnTab)
        RawExtract = .Cells(fnRow, fnColumn).Text
        FnDateExtract = Format(RawExtract, "mmm yyyy")
    End With
End Function
```

I keep getting into this problem where the function would read strings '11/1/2018' and 'Nov-2018' and return the result 'Nov 2019'. I have no clue why 2019 (but the problem only appeared from January 1, 2019 onward. How strange.)

**Question:**
As a temporary solution, is there a way to return the year minus 1? Something akin to FnDateExtract = Format(RawExtract, "mmm **yyyy - 1**")?

If you could help me solve the problem why the function always misreads strings by exactly 1 year, that'd also help a lot. Thanks!

**Edit**
RonRosenfeld below suggested that the function would only extract the current year. I did a few tests and it seems like it would also extract 2017 as 2019. Not sure why that is. Still looking for a solution.

Comment: Are the dates, actual dates or text that look like dates?

Comment: Are you sure you are pointing at the correct sheet and workbook?

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. Despite the format of the date, it still works for me. As @ScottCraner said, are you sure you're pointing to the intended sheet and workbook?

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes I am sure I am pointing to the right sheet and workbook. I used this function at least 100 times for the entire year last year without a problem, but the problem only happened in the past few weeks where it now gets the year wrong. I also use the function on multiple sheets and they consistently get things wrong

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue, so have no advice beyond what I stated in my comments.  There is something with the data not the function.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks. If I read 'Aug 2018' from another file, it would return 'Aug 2019'.   If I read '07/1/2018' from a 3rd file, it would return 'Jul 2019'. I find it hard to believe it's a data issue, but also not a function issue. Really seems to be a bug to me...

Comment: There is not much we can do. As stated above, we cannot replicate the issue.

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to `Format` a string.  You will probably always get the current year in the output.  Try changing to: `Dim RawExtract As Date`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Ron, I think you are right, I did a few tests and it always returns the current calendar year. Dim RawExtract As Date does NOT work though.

Comment: If the solution suggested by @user10947436 also does not work, I'd need a sample of your actual data in order to see what is going wrong.  You could copy/paste that as text into your original question, or upload a file to some sharing site and post a link in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the IsDate check combined with the CDate conversion to achieve the correct string representing a date.

```
Option Explicit

Function FnDateExtract(fnFile As String, fnTab As String, fnRow As Long, fnColumn As Variant)
    With Workbooks(fnFile).Worksheets(fnTab)
        If IsDate(.Cells(fnRow, fnColumn).Text) Then
            FnDateExtract = Format(CDate(.Cells(fnRow, fnColumn).Text), "mmm yyyy")
        End If
    End With
End Function
```